# PowerShell Compare-Object mismatch

Tags: powershell

I am trying to compare two objects one by creating an array [object 1] that is matched by importing CSV file [object 2].

Example:

```
$userList = Get-AzureRmADGroup -DisplayName abc | Get-RecursiveAzureAdGroupMember
$userList | Add-Member @{GroupName = $groupName } -PassThru
$finalList += $userList

$targetFile2 = "Baseline.csv"

$BaselineReport = Import-Csv -Path $targetFile2 -Encoding UTF8 -Delimiter "," -ErrorAction Stop

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $FinalList -DifferenceObject $BaselineReport  -Property Name, DisplayName, Id, Type, Group, GroupName -IncludeEqual
```

**"baseline.csv"** file has the same records from **finalist**.
But there is a mismatch from compare-object while some are matching most of them are a mismatch.

Comment: Does your CSV file include all the same properties you get with `Get-RecursiveAzureAdGroupMember`. Do you get different results if you specify `-All $true` on the `Get-RecursiveAzureAdGroupMember`?

Comment: The CSV file includes all the same property from Get-RecursiveAzureAdGroupMember .

Comment: @user3929769 - are you totally sure the two collections contain identical items? i ask that because the _default screen display_ of objects is not complete. you will _often_ get different results from `$Collection[0]` and `$Collection[0] | Select-Object -Property *`.